# Do the Scout’s skirmish benefits trigger from the Benign Transposition spell being cast on the Scout?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, class-feature, movement, forced-movement

The Scout class from *Complete Adventurer* (p. 12) gets skirmish benefits in any round after she moves at least 10 feet.

The *Spell Compendium* includes Benign Transposition (p. 27), which swaps the positions of any two willing targets.

If a scout is swapped by someone else casting Benign Transposition, do her skirmish benefits trigger? Does it matter when the caster acts relative to her?

Comment: You might also be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/34012/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan indeed I was! Unfortunately it didn’t help with this specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A scout relies on mobility to deal extra damage and improve her defense. She deals an extra 1d6 points of damage on all attacks she makes during any round in which **she moves** at least 10 feet.

<sup>(*Complete Adventurer* pg. 12)</sup>

This is literally all we’ve got. The clause “she moves” is ambiguous in English—it could refer to her moving under her own power, or it could refer to any change of position at all. RAW, either interpretation is valid. And teleportation seems “different” enough that maybe it wouldn’t count even if it *was* under her own power—though that’s definitely not RAW. We don’t even have a lot of description to base speculation on: why does “mobility” result in extra damage? Is it like a “momentum, speed” thing? (And does teleportation conserve that?) Or is it a “being fast and not where your opponent expected” thing? There’s no telling.

Unfortunately, there’s really not a whole lot to go on here. My personal position is that the scout is a weak class, and doesn’t need any wrenches thrown in anywhere: I would allow it.

Answer (score 2):

### Probably not.

> Complete Adventurer Errata in bold
>
> The second sentence of the skirmish class feature
>   should read as follows (new text indicated in red): She
>   deals an extra 1d6 points of damage on all attacks she
>   makes during any round in which she moves at least 10
>   feet **away from where she was at the start of her turn.
>   The extra damage applies only to attacks made after the
>   scout has moved at least 10 feet. The skirmish ability
>   cannot be used while mounted.**

-

> Teleportation SRD
>
> A teleportation spell **transports** one or more creatures or objects a great distance. The most powerful of these spells can cross planar boundaries. Unlike summoning spells, the **transportation** is (unless otherwise noted) one-way and not dispellable.
>
> Teleportation is **instantaneous** travel through the Astral Plane. Anything that blocks astral travel also blocks teleportation.

Since the magic is transporting you instantaneously, it's something else moving you, kinda like a mount transporting you from one place to another. Skirmish seems to want you to do the movement.

I agree with KRyan that the scout is weak, but there are many other good ways to get extra movement that will count towards the Scout's Skirmish ability.